# Cant save '\r\n' tag from Enviroment.NewLine into database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My string looks like this:

```
string output = input + Enviroment.NewLine; // output == text\r\n
```

I saving it to database like this:

```
this.db.Table.Add(new Result { Output = output});
this.db.SaveChanges();
```

And when i look into `SQL Object Explorer`, `Enviroment.NewLine` is not saved into database (in `Output` column i get `"text"` instead of `"text\r\n"`. My question is, how to save `string` with `NewLine` tag into my database? (`Output` is string property in DB). While im debugging, `output` is properly stored as `"text\r\n"`

**EDIT**

Ok, i get it, in my database my string looks like this:

```
1 text
2
```

Instead of

```
1 text\r\n
```

So how to save it as raw tag?

Comment: Are you sure the new line character not save or just not visible?
Try retrieving it from the DB and see what the value of the string is.

Comment: I checked it, in my database and when i "retriving" it there is no `\r\n` tag

Comment: Ok, i get it, look into my edit

Comment: What I mean is retrieve it from the code:
var result = this.db.Table.Where(/* predicate to find your entity */);
var output = result.Output; // see if the newline character was actually saved.

Comment: is it C# windows or console app?

Comment: You should never save returns in a database. You will have problems later when you start to use the data.

Comment: What is your intended use for those characters when you retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is a character. This character has the value 10 if converted to an int:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"\n - " + ((int)'\n'));
```

The question is, what do you want to store in your DB?

If you want to save a test like this

> abc\ncde

Or like this

> abc
>   cde

Printing out your strings to the console will show you what you store in your db:

```
Console.WriteLine("abc\ncde"); // This output is
Console.WriteLine("abc" + ((char)10) + "cde"); // equal to this

// If you want to store a backslash ('\') you have to escape it:
Console.WriteLine("abc\\ncde"); // This output is
// Or tell C# to ignore escape-sequences in this string by adding an @:
Console.WriteLine(@"abc\ncde"); // equal to this
```

We see now that "\n" is only Visual-Studios way to show you a NewLine (char 10).

Answer (score 1):

Use `CHAR(13)`, hope it will work for you like below code:-

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(100)
SET @text = 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13) + 'This is line 2.'
SELECT @text
```

If you are using some web application you have to save the `<br/>`（Html tags）into database directly.